# Matrices such that $A^2+B^2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B\in M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ be matrices such that $A^2+B^2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}AB$ and $\det(AB-BA) >0$. Prove that $n$ is a multiple of $16$.
I tried to make substitutions such as $A=X+Y$ and $B=X-Y$, but they clearly do not work because of the ugly constant. I don't have any idea how $16$ actually relates to that constant, so I am at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the complex case, but if the matrices are real, the problem can be solved as follows. Let $r=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ and $z=\frac12\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} - i\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\right)$. Then $r=z+\bar{z}$ and
$$
(A-zB)\left(A-\bar{z}B\right)=A^2+B^2-\bar{z}AB-zBA=(r-\bar{z})AB-zBA=z(AB-BA).
$$
Taking determinants on both sides, we get (as $A$ and $B$ are real)
$$
|\det(A-zB)|^2=z^n\det(AB-BA).
$$
Since $\det(AB-BA)>0$ and $z\ne0$, the above equation implies that $z^n$ is a positive real number. However, it is not hard to verify that $z$ is a primitive $16$-th root of unity. Therefore $n$ is divisible by $16$.

Comment: Which part uses that $A$ and $B$ are real? $\text{det}((A-zB)(A-\bar{z}B))=|\text{det}(A-zB)|^2$?

Comment: @kccu Yes. In general, $\overline{\det(A-zB)}=\det(\overline{A}-\bar{z}\overline{B})$. So, when $A$ and $B$ are real, we have $\overline{\det(A-zB)}=\det(A-\bar{z}B)$.

Comment: In fact, $A$ and $B$ are real, it was a typo. Excellent solution!